# Call to undefined method Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::getMaxQueryLength()

Tags: magento2

Why do i get

Call to undefined method Tagalys\Tglssearch\Helper\Data::getMaxQueryLength() in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x\magento2\app\code\Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory.php on line 76

**My helper:**

```
namespace Tagalys\Tglssearch\Helper;
use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper 
{
     public function __construct(        
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Tagalys\Tglssearch\Model\Client\Connector $tglssearchClientConnector,
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $themeHtmlPager
)   {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;              //to use getValue() 
        $this->tglssearchClientConnector = $tglssearchClientConnector;
        $this->themeHtmlPager = $themeHtmlPager;
    }
   ....
     public function getResultUrl($query = null)
{
    echo 'tag geturl';die;
    return $this->_getUrl(
        'tglssearch/result',
        ['_query' => [QueryFactory::QUERY_VAR_NAME => $query], '_secure' => $this->_request->isSecure()]
    );
}
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is all of your helpers code, there is simply no method "getMaxQueryLength" which can be called..